# Using PHP to issue recommendations based off of HTML checkbox selections

Tags: php, html, checkbox

The following is an HTML form which is processed by the PHP code below. The intention is to determine which types of marketing the user is engaging in and issue recommendations accordingly, ie the PHP function will grow to more than the simple two recommendations seen below. My problem is being able to issue recommendations based off of which checkboxes have been selected. So if TV and Radio are selected, I want to issue this recommendation. If search and mobile are selected, I want to issue this recommendation. As is, all that echoes back is "You can do more to market your dealership" regardless of how many checkboxes I select. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**NOTE: The form already uses the POST method.**

HTML FORM

```
 <p>Marketing Mix:</p>    
 <input type="checkbox" name="TV" value="TV">TV<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="Radio" value="Radio">Radio<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="Search" value="Search">Search<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="Mobile" value="Mobile">Mobile<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="Mail" value="Mail">Direct Mail<br>
 <br>
```

PHP

```
 function marketMix () {
 $tv = (isset($_POST['TV']));
 $radio = (isset($_POST['Radio']));
 $search = (isset($_POST['Search']));
 $mobile = (isset($_POST['Mobile']));
 $mail = (isset($_POST['Mail']));
 if ($tv && $radio && $search && $mobile && $mail) {
     echo "You are running a comprehensive ad campaign.";
 } else {
     echo "You can do more to market your dealership.";
    }
 }
```

Comment: done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($_POST)` to see what you're really receiving in PHP? you haven't shown the rest of the form, so maybe you're submitting via GET instead. And as written, you have to select **ALL** of the checkboxes, otherwise the only possible solution is "do more".

Comment: I am submitting via POST.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do a better check for the checkbox value.

```
(isset($_POST['TV']) ? $_POST['TV'] == 'on' : false)
```

I also have seen the use of !empty($_POST['TV']), but I haven't used that before.

Comment: false. checkboxes do not submit along with the form if they're NOT checked. the mere presence of the checkbox's name in the submitted data means it was checked. checking for a value can be useful in some situations, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: So what is the solution?